# Remove vertical scrollbar from react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I want to remove the vertical scroll bard from react-data-grid. I didn't find any configuration setting for the same. However, I manage to do it with css but I can't adjust the column to take 100% width as the space still exits in header column row. Any suggestion on this.

My fix for scrollbar

```
.react-grid-Canvas {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you need to achieve this using css only, plugin author is calculating its width based on the columns you provided.

Comment: can you provide the code in codesandbox